# Check if Dictionary value is an array

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, dynamic, jil

I have a dictionary in my code which holds key value pairs from 3rd party API call.
I get the API response as a serialize string. So I hold these values in a dictionary like below

```
var res = await APICall();
var bookingTypes = Jil.JSON.DeserializeDynamic(res)["Bookings"][0];
var bookingData = (IDictionary<string, object>)bookingTypes;
```

some of the properties in bookingTypes are an array. Sometimes these arrays are empty and because of that I get an error when I'm trying get the value of first element of that array

```
string test = bookingData.ContainsKey("OrderCodes") ? bookingTypes.OrderCodes?[0] : "";
```

In above case bookingTypes.OrderCodes is empty []. I cannot check for array length since it is a dynamic value. How can I overcome this issue?

**UPDATE #1**

Added API response

```json
{
   "Bookings":[
      {
         "PersonalID":1025,
         "Name":"Brian K. Thomas",
         "OrderCodes":[
            
         ],
         "PrevOrders":[
            2390,
            3115
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

When I try to get value from the dictionary this is what I get (immediate window). Please note that "PrveOrders" is another array like property but with values. Added it also you can compare it

```
bookingData.TryGetValue("PrveOrders", out object kws4);
true
kws4
{[239]}
    Dynamic View: Expanding the Dynamic View will get the dynamic members for the object
bookingData.TryGetValue("OrderCodes", out object kws5);
true
kws5
{[]}
    Dynamic View: Expanding the Dynamic View will get the dynamic members for the object
```

Comment: Why can't you do `bookingTypes.OrderCodes.Length`?

Comment: BTW why are you deserializing dynamically? It seems that you are expecting the response to have some structure.

Comment: Can you share with us a sample APICall response?

Comment: @Charlieface its a dynamic property. ".Length" is not available. If I need to use it I will have to cast into an array first. That's the thing I'm after

Comment: @PeterCsala response is added

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also provide an example when OrderCodes is not empty?

Comment: @PeterCsala when the OrderCodes is not empty, it looks like this {[239]}

Comment: `TryGetValue("PrveOrders",` did you mean `TryGetValue("PrevOrders",` right?

Comment: [Dotnet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2RFMVJ) Are you looking for this?

Comment: @PeterCsala I was so stupid. .Length is not suggested by framework because of it's dynamic property. But it works. Thanks

Comment: @user2837480 Shall I post an answer to close this topic?

Comment: sure. Please do @PeterCsala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [JIL documentation points out you](https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Jil#dynamic-deserialization) could use

- member access on objects
- and `.Length` on arrays

in case of dynamic deserialization.

```
var json = "{\"Bookings\":[{\"PersonalID\":1025,\"Name\":\"Brian K. Thomas\",\"OrderCodes\":[],\"PrevOrders\":[2390, 3115]}]}";
var semiParsed = Jil.JSON.DeserializeDynamic(json);

var orderCodes = semiParsed.Bookings[0].OrderCodes;
var orderCode = orderCodes.Length > 0 ? orderCodes[0] : "";
Console.WriteLine(orderCode); //prints empty line

var prevOrders = semiParsed.Bookings[0].PrevOrders;
var prevOrder = prevOrders.Length > 0 ? prevOrders[0] : "";
Console.WriteLine(prevOrder); //prints 2390
```

Dotnet fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2RFMVJ

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
var check = bookingData.ContainsKey("OrderCodes");
if (check.GetElementType()==?) {
    //   
}
```

?